# Solve system of diff equations using laplace transform and evaluate x(1)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I keep getting the wrong answer, and wolphram seems to back me up.

Here's the system of equations

[image]

The answer I get for $x(1)$ is 10492.1... The supposedly right answer is -1426.16

Can anyone try this problem and tell me what they find out?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

Using Cramer's Rule I got

$X(s)=\frac{10}{(s-9)(s-3)}-\frac{20}{s(s-9)(s-3)}$

Using partial fractions decomposition I found the inverse laplace transform and got:

$(10/6-20/54)e^{9t}+(-10/6+20/18)e^{3t}-20/27$

Comment: Could you show me your procedure?

Comment: I'll add chunks of it, but the key points since it is kind of a long problem, is that OK?

Comment: I'm not given the original system, only the system of equations after making the transformation. I've put that system in the beginning of my post.

Comment: I meant given not giving, lol.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too! Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the answer's wrong. Let's just solve for $Y(s)$ from the second equation, $$Y(s) = -\frac{X(s)}{s-2}.$$ Subbing this into the first equation gives, after rearranging,
$$
X(s) = \frac{10s-20}{s(s-3)(s-9)},
$$
the partial fraction decomposition of which is
$$
X(s) = \frac{35}{27(s-9)} - \frac{5}{9(s-3)} - \frac{20}{27s}.
$$
Note that we could sub this into our first line to get $Y(s)$. Inverting the transform,
$$
x(t) = \frac{35}{27}\mathrm{e}^{9t} - \frac{5}{9}\mathrm{e}^{3t} - \frac{20}{27},
$$
so $x(1) \approx 10492.098$.